# IServiceCollection Add Authentication vs Add Identity

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

This two feature looks more complex to me. I have .net core web application with Cookie authentication. I have configured every thing and works fine as well.

My question is, when we already have method for AddAuthentication and AddAuthorization under IServiceCollection which full fill all the our requirements. (i.e. user, roles, policy etc). What is need to AddIdentity object here?

Are they different from each other? Lets say, I have cookie base authentication than I already have User identity under HttpContext. What makes it different if i AddIdentity over it.

This might be confusion for end user. But real difference can answer my question.

Thanks.

Comment: `AddIdentity` refers to identity framework. which encompasses a combination of what you have already said to have done manually. Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x

Comment: Agree, but why object of both are inter related. i.e. If I use cookie authentication and want to update my ClaimPrincipal, the only way I can do is using object SignInManager class which requires ApplicationUser as type. Now to initiate ApplicationUser I have to addidentity as service.

Comment: AddIdentity will add a Framework that knowns how to persist User, Role, Claim related data to the Database. Otherwise we have to handle all these data Persistence Use Cases.

Answer (score 1):

Basically You should Add only one . Authentication or Identity. If you are using Identity
then you don't have to configure the authentication manually Asp.net core identity automatically does that.

Comment: Since Identity auto invokes the .AddAuthentication, how do I tell it to make use of JWT scheme rather than cookies?